# How to pass an array as an input parameter in a function in vyper?

Tags: arrays, vyper

Let's say I have a function and I want to pass `my_array` as an input parameter, how do I do that in vyper?

This is an example, but it throws a compiler error.

```py
def my_func(my_array: uint256[]):
  pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the length of the array:

```py
def my_func(my_array: uint256[100]):
  pass
```

This also works for `DynArray`s

Comment: Works for array of `struct`s too. Structs passed as tuples. Also works for `DynArray[]`.